# How to patch / repair interior plastic door material?

Tags: subaru, interior, impreza

This is a roughly 1-1/2" (5cm) tear in the material of the rear door of my Subaru:

[image: torn]

I don't know how it originally got damaged but by the time I noticed it I think one of my (lovely) kids had torn it off. I do not have the missing piece.

In terms of repair my #1 priority is to protect the area and make sure this won't get any worse. I'm not too troubled too achieve a perfect cosmetic repair.

I don't know what material this is likely to be or what a suitable patching / covering method would be?  I've read that cars may be "vinyl" but a lot of patch kits I've seen seem to be for "leather" and/or seats, not this sort of situation.

Thanks

Comment: In the short term: gaffer tape / duct tape. Have you looked up "vinyl upholstery repair kit"?

Comment: @WeatherVane I wasn't sure if vinyl really was the right material, or if it varies or anything. Is any normal car interior pretty much the same as any other?

Comment: Considering what I see in the image, it surely looks like vinyl to me.

Comment: It would have to be a pretty good repair for the edges of the patch not to scuff up.